# security concerns around storing user data on Google App Engine

Tags: security, google-app-engine

Are there any security or compliance concerns around storing user data, (name, email, address, tel) in Google App datastore?

Comment: This isn't really a programming question - it's a legal one. Security and compliance issues depend on your local jurisdiction and the nature of the information you're storing, and I doubt anyone here is qualified to answer them authoritatively.

Comment: I agree with Nick. BTW what kind of security are you expecting with a server related to data which you think could be a concern with Google App Engine and not with the other servers?

Comment: But it's a valid question any kind of sensitive data is to go on GAE. Maybe retry the question at serverfault.com? It's not the same as with other servers (at least not those you administrate yourself) since as a deployer you can't know exactly where the data will be stored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In their privacy policy Google say they adhere to the [US Safe Harbor privacy principles](http://www.export.gov/safeharbor/) which says:

> Organizations must take **reasonable**
>   precautions to protect personal
>   information from loss, misuse and
>   unauthorized access, disclosure,
>   alteration and destruction.

If your application has to meet specific compliance rules that deal with storage of data then you probably can't use google app engine because you don't have control over what google do internally.

This is probably the same for other shared hosting providers.